# How to create a custom column (sortable) in DT::datatable

Tags: r, datatable, dt

Let say I have below `data-table` -

```
    library(DT)
     d = data.frame(
      names = rownames(mtcars),
      date = as.Date('2015-03-23') + 1:32,
      time = as.POSIXct('2015-03-23 12:00:00', tz = 'UTC') + (1:32) * 5000,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )

    datatable(d, filter = 'bottom', options = list(pageLength = 5))
```

Now I want to create a new column in the `data-table` by combining `date+time+some-other-string` as `date_time`. This new column `date_time` should be sortable based only on `date` part (not the `time` part nor `string` part). I also want to give different colour for `date` part and `time` part.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: couldnt you sort just by date, then?
regarding color: you could use html code inside of DT or use a callback as in https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html 4.4 and assign different background-color's

Comment: This scenario may arise when I want to hide both standalone date and time column instead only display date-time and want to make it sortable based on specific criteria. I wanted to have a general approach like numeric+text (sortable by numeric) etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort the fourth column according to the second column:

```
library(DT)

render <- JS(
  "function(data, type, row, meta){",
  "  if(type === 'sort' || type === 'type'){",
  "    return row[2];",
  "  } else {",
  "    return data;",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

d = data.frame(
  names = rownames(mtcars),
  date = as.Date('2015-03-23') + 1:32,
  time = as.POSIXct('2015-03-23 12:00:00', tz = 'UTC') + (1:32) * 5000,
  otherColumn = mtcars$mpg,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

datatable(d, filter = 'bottom', 
          options = list(
            pageLength = 5,
            columnDefs = list(
              list(targets = 4, render = render)
            )
          )
)
```

For the colors, you can do:

```
render <- JS(
  "function(data, type, row, meta){",
  "  if(type === 'sort' || type === 'type'){",
  "    return row[2];",
  "  } else if(type === 'display'){",
  "    var date = '<span style=\"color:red;\">' + row[2] + ' </span>';",
  "    var time = '<span style=\"color:blue;\">' + row[3] + ' </span>';",
  "    var other = '<span style=\"color:green;\">' + data + '</span>';",
  "    return date + time + other;",
  "  } else {",
  "    return data;",
  "  }",
  "}"
)

d = data.frame(
  names = rownames(mtcars),
  date = as.Date('2015-03-23') + 1:32,
  time = as.POSIXct('2015-03-23 12:00:00', tz = 'UTC') + (1:32) * 5000,
  otherColumn = stringi::stri_rand_strings(32, 3),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

datatable(d, filter = 'bottom', 
          options = list(
            pageLength = 5,
            columnDefs = list(
              list(targets = 4, render = render)
            )
          )
)
```