# How to sort a custom column in DT::datatable

Tags: datatable, shiny, dt

This is in continuation of another post here -
[How to create a custom column (sortable) in DT::datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61669426/how-to-create-a-custom-column-sortable-in-dtdatatable?noredirect=1#comment109084799_61669426)

The approach presented there appears to be failing for below dataset when it is placed within a `shiny` app.

I wanted to sort according to `Col_9` in the dataset.

Below is my `Shiny` app

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("aaa", height = '400px')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$aaa = 
            DT::renderDT({
            df = 
            structure(list(Col__1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "C", 
"D", "G", "G", "H", "H", "J", "K", "K", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"O", "P", "P", "R", "T", "T", "T", "U", "U", "W"), Col__2 = c(1234, 
1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 
1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 
1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234), Col__3 = c(1234, 1234, 
1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 
1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 
1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234), Col__4 = c(NA, 36, NA, 1, 
4, 1, NA, 65, NA, 396, 7, 2, 3, 29, 4, 185, 651, NA, 1, NA, 2, 
NA, 27, 92, 35, 29, NA, 60, 1, 144), Col__5 = c(NA, 1012, NA, 
12, 350, 98, NA, 3925, NA, 4729, 327, 5, 87, 310, 30, 1854, 13013, 
NA, 1, NA, 122, NA, 1354, 1629, 3278, 450, NA, 1808, 21, 948), 
    Col__6 = c(1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 
    1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 
    1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 
    1234, 1234), Col__7 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    Col__8 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Col__9 = c("-", 
    " 36 (2%)", "-", "  1 (2%)", "  4 (1%)", "  1 (1%)", "-", 
    " 65 (1%)", "-", "396 (6%)", "  7 (1%)", "  2 (4%)", "  3 (2%)", 
    " 29 (4%)", "  4 (1%)", "185 (6%)", "651 (4%)", "-", "  1 (8%)", 
    "-", "  2 (1%)", "-", " 27 (2%)", " 92 (3%)", " 35 (1%)", 
    " 29 (3%)", "-", " 60 (2%)", "  1 (2%)", "144 (10%)"), Col__10 = c(2.5, 
    2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 
    2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 
    2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")

{  ### Few Important Definitions
                    Render3 = JS(
                                "function(data, type, row, meta){",
                                "  if(type === 'sort' || type === 'type'){",
                                "    return row[4];",
                                "  } else {",
                                "    return data;",
                                "  }",
                                "}"
                            )
                }

datatable(df, 
                            callback = JS("$('table.dataTable.no-footer').css('border-bottom', '1px solid #b7b7b7');"),
                            options = list(pageLength = dim(df)[1], bLengthChange = FALSE, autoWidth = FALSE, bInfo = FALSE, searching = FALSE, info = FALSE, bPaginate = FALSE,
                                            order = list(list(7, 'desc')),
                                            columnDefs = 
                                                list(
                                                    list(width = '40%', targets = 1, className = 'dt-center dt-center1'), 

                                                    list(width = '0%', targets = 2, className = 'dt-center dt-center1', visible = FALSE),
                                                    list(width = '0%', targets = 3, className = 'dt-center dt-center1', visible = FALSE),
                                                    list(width = '0%', targets = 4, className = 'dt-center dt-center1', visible = FALSE),
                                                    list(width = '0%', targets = 5, className = 'dt-center dt-center1', visible = FALSE),
                                                    list(width = '0%', targets = 6, className = 'dt-center dt-center1', visible = FALSE),


                                                    list(width = '15%', targets = 9,  className = 'dt-center dt-center1', visible = TRUE, render = Render3),


                                                    list(targets = 0, visible = FALSE)
                                                ))) 


        })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However surprisingly, this same approach is perfectly working outside of `shiny` app.

Below is the snapshot of the problem when run within a `Shiny-app` -

[image]

Any pointer towards the right approach will be very helpful.

Comment: What is failing? I ran your app but I don't see. What is the expectation?

Comment: I have put a snapshot of the problem. Please note that this problem is appears ONLY when run within Shiny-app.